# barplot ylim set to subset of y range but barplot still plots entire y range

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis

I'm trying to plot a vector of data using the `barplot()` function in basic `R` graphics. Since the differences between the values are small, I want to show a subset of the y range to make the differences more easily distinguishable. However, when I change the y scale to a subset of y range, the bars in the barplot and not cut off at the minimum value of y axis scale. How do I modify the barplot code to have the bars cut off at the minimum value in my y axis scale?

```
data = c(8,9,10)
barplot(data, ylim=c(2,11))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `xpd` (`?barplot`):

```
barplot(data, ylim = c(2,11), xpd = F)
```

[image]